# How to toggle multiple divs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have several divs which should be shown / hidden when the corresponding button is clicked. In the initial state all buttons and all divs are visible. When the first button is clicked, only the corresponding div should be visible. When the second button is clicked, the corresponding div should be visible as well etc. The click on a button should toggle the state of the button and the corresponding div.

I'm not sure if this can be realized without placing a cookie or local storage token. So far I've created the following code, which only allows me to deactivate the divs with one first click.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('inactive');
        $('#mydiv'+$(this).attr('target')).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="button" target="1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button" target="2">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button" target="3">Button 3</button>
</div>

<div id="mydiv1">
  <p>Div 1</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv2">
  <p>Div 2</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv3">
  <p>Div 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of ID write same class name for all the div and toggle that

Comment: _"without placing a cookie or local storage token"_ - you would need those, if you wanted to persist the selection across page reloads.

Comment: What if you "untick" all the buttons?  ie returns to initial state - should you have none or all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to toggle only the button/div that you just clicked, first you have to reset previous state of all elements to initial (remove class `inactive` and show all divs) and only than toggle state.

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
      let checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
      $('.inactive').removeClass('inactive');
      
      if (checked.length == 0) {
        $('.subdiv').show();
        
        return;
      }
      
      $('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').closest('label').addClass('inactive');

      $('.subdiv').hide();
      
      checked.each(function () {
        $('#mydiv' + $(this).val()).toggle();
      });
    });
});
```

```css
.inactive {
  color: red;
}

label input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="1"/>Button 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="2"/>Button 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="3"/>Button 3</label>
</div>

<div id="mydiv1" class="subdiv">
  <p>Div 1</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv2" class="subdiv">
  <p>Div 2</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv3" class="subdiv">
  <p>Div 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to the opposite of what OP requires - "*When the first button is clicked, only the corresponding div should be visible*" - not: when button 1 is clicked it's hidden and all the others should be visible.

Comment: @freedomn-m Just matter of `$('.subdiv').hide();`/`$('.subdiv').show();`, updated answer

Comment: Suspected it would be a small change, but now it works like a radio - only one can be selected.  "*When the second button is clicked, the corresponding div should be **visible as well** etc"* - it's a toggle on/off with multiple visible, just: starts with all visible, first click all hide except clicked, 2+ clicks toggle

Comment: Maybe the initial reset can be limited with an if statement and a variable wich is defined the first time any button is clicked?

Comment: @Bernhard Please check updated answer. Converted every button to checkbox, made it look like buttons (if needed). Does this solution acts as required now?

Comment: The only "misleading" part in this solution is the fact, that the inactive state should be applied to the checkboxes "not checked" and not the other way round.

Comment: @Justinas Thank you! For some strange reason the .hide() function is not applied if the value of the chechbox / id of the div is set to 3 (no CSS conflict). But I guess this has to be a local problem. If I change the number 3 to anything elese, it works.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to initially hide the divs and show the correct one when the right button is clicked.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#mydiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/*
  Hide all divs that have an id starting with "mydiv"
*/

div[id^="mydiv"] {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="button" target="1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button" target="2">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button" target="3">Button 3</button>
</div>

<div id="mydiv1">
  <p>Div 1</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv2">
  <p>Div 2</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv3">
  <p>Div 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: _In the initial state all buttons and all divs are visible_ - OP

Answer (score 0):

Have you to use a toggle or you can also solve it with a walk around?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
  $('.inactive').removeClass('inactive');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.subdiv').show();
 
    $('.mydiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/*
  Hide all divs that have an id starting with "mydiv"
*/

.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="button" target="1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button" target="2">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button" target="3">Button 3</button>
</div>

<div class="mydiv1" hidden>
  <p>Div 1</p>
</div>

<div class="mydiv2" hidden>
  <p>Div 2</p>
</div>

<div class="mydiv3" hidden>
  <p>Div 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean "work around"?

Comment: It works concerning the toogle function and the sate of the buttons but the divs are initially not visible.

Comment: I am trying another solution as soon as I can I will share it with you it should work

Comment: I think that #Justinas solution is the best one